# SSRS - Can I use an expression calculation from two separate Tablix within one Chart?

Tags: reporting-services, expression

I have two data tablix (same dataset) with filters, within a report and have used an expression to calculate a percentage value see attached....
[image: Data Output]

I want to use the two % values from the two tablix data output so they appear on a chart like the excel version below....
[image: Required Chart Output]

The expression i'm using to generate the % calculation is shown below.....

```
=FORMAT(
        SUM(
             SUM(IIF(Fields!DataType.Value="COT Retention",Fields!DataCount.Value,0),"MonthYear1")
             /
             SUM(
                SUM(IIF(Fields!DataType.Value="COT Loss",Fields!DataCount.Value,0),"MonthYear1") +
                SUM(IIF(Fields!DataType.Value="COT Retention",Fields!DataCount.Value,0),"MonthYear1")
                )
            ) * 100,
        0.00
        )+"%"
```

Can anyone advise me how I may achieve this?

I have tried inserting the attached expression(minus the Formatting part).....

```
SUM( SUM(IIF(Fields!DataType.Value="COT Retention",Fields!DataCount.Value,0),"MonthYear1") / SUM( SUM(IIF(Fields!DataType.Value="COT Loss",Fields!DataCount.Value,0),"MonthYear1") + SUM(IIF(Fields!DataType.Value="COT Retention",Fields!DataCount.Value,0),"MonthYear1") ) ) * 100
```

within the chart so it looks like this.....
[image: Chart Properties]

But get the following errors.....

```
[rsIncompatibleNestedAggregateScopes] The Y expression for the chart 'Chart2' specifies multiple incompatible scopes in the same aggregate expression.  Nested aggregates cannot specify multiple peer groups and cannot specify both child groups and nested data regions.  The scopes for all nested aggregates must be the same as, a parent of, or a child of the scopes all other nested aggregates in the same expression.

[rsIncompatibleNestedAggregateScopes] The Y expression for the chart 'Chart2' specifies multiple incompatible scopes in the same aggregate expression.  Nested aggregates cannot specify multiple peer groups and cannot specify both child groups and nested data regions.  The scopes for all nested aggregates must be the same as, a parent of, or a child of the scopes all other nested aggregates in the same expression.

[rsIncompatibleNestedAggregateScopes] The Y expression for the chart 'Chart2' specifies multiple incompatible scopes in the same aggregate expression.  Nested aggregates cannot specify multiple peer groups and cannot specify both child groups and nested data regions.  The scopes for all nested aggregates must be the same as, a parent of, or a child of the scopes all other nested aggregates in the same expression.

[rsIncompatibleNestedAggregateScopes] The Y expression for the chart 'Chart2' specifies multiple incompatible scopes in the same aggregate expression.  Nested aggregates cannot specify multiple peer groups and cannot specify both child groups and nested data regions.  The scopes for all nested aggregates must be the same as, a parent of, or a child of the scopes all other nested aggregates in the same expression.

[rsIncompatibleNestedAggregateScopes] The Y expression for the chart 'Chart2' specifies multiple incompatible scopes in the same aggregate expression.  Nested aggregates cannot specify multiple peer groups and cannot specify both child groups and nested data regions.  The scopes for all nested aggregates must be the same as, a parent of, or a child of the scopes all other nested aggregates in the same expression.

[rsIncompatibleNestedAggregateScopes] The Y expression for the chart 'Chart2' specifies multiple incompatible scopes in the same aggregate expression.  Nested aggregates cannot specify multiple peer groups and cannot specify both child groups and nested data regions.  The scopes for all nested aggregates must be the same as, a parent of, or a child of the scopes all other nested aggregates in the same expression.

[rsInvalidNestedAggregateScope] The Y expression for the chart 'Chart2' specifies a scope that is not valid for a nested aggregate.  The scope must be the same name of the scope specified by the outer aggregate or the name of a group or data region that is contained in the scope specified by the outer aggregate.

[rsInvalidNestedAggregateScope] The Y expression for the chart 'Chart2' specifies a scope that is not valid for a nested aggregate.  The scope must be the same name of the scope specified by the outer aggregate or the name of a group or data region that is contained in the scope specified by the outer aggregate.

[rsInvalidNestedAggregateScope] The Y expression for the chart 'Chart2' specifies a scope that is not valid for a nested aggregate.  The scope must be the same name of the scope specified by the outer aggregate or the name of a group or data region that is contained in the scope specified by the outer aggregate.

[rsInvalidNestedAggregateScope] The Y expression for the chart 'Chart2' specifies a scope that is not valid for a nested aggregate.  The scope must be the same name of the scope specified by the outer aggregate or the name of a group or data region that is contained in the scope specified by the outer aggregate.

[rsInvalidNestedAggregateScope] The Y expression for the chart 'Chart2' specifies a scope that is not valid for a nested aggregate.  The scope must be the same name of the scope specified by the outer aggregate or the name of a group or data region that is contained in the scope specified by the outer aggregate.

[rsInvalidNestedAggregateScope] The Y expression for the chart 'Chart2' specifies a scope that is not valid for a nested aggregate.  The scope must be the same name of the scope specified by the outer aggregate or the name of a group or data region that is contained in the scope specified by the outer aggregate.
```

I just want to display the two different % values on the one chart....can it be done?

Comment: What is "MonthYear1", is that the name of your dataset of a row/column group? If it's a rowgroup, then you can't  used that in the chart as it's referring to the tablix. Your chart data will come from the dataset so you must build your expressions over the whole dataset query result. One more thing, avoid `*100 ==> convert to string ==> append a % symbol` . just return the actual value (e.g. 0.256) and then apply formatting on the text box (e.g. "p2") so it shows as "25.60%"

Comment: Hi yes - "MonthYear1" is a column group - can this be used? or is it both row and column groups cannot be used?

Comment: The row and column groups only apply to the tablix they are created in, you cannot reference them outside of that (from a chart etc.). To start, just try removing all the `, "MonthYear"` references from your chart expressions, that might just work. If not, show a sample of your dataset output and we can look at rewriting the expressions.

Comment: That's great  Alan - thank you - it worked by just removing the column grouping reference as you suggested. I now look to have what I want.